# Is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy$ a PDF where $f_x,f_Y$ are both PDFS

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, improper-integrals, convolution

Is $(f_X*f_Y)(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy$ a PDF  where $f_X,f_Y$ are both PDFS

I know that when $X,Y$ are independent then the formula is a probability convolution funcntion $(f_X*f_Y)(z)$.

But when $X,Y$ are dependent, is this property still true? In other words, can we prove $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f_X*f_Y)(z)dz=1$, I have no idea on how to evaluate this integral.

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus Did you mean that if X and Y are dependent then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)dy$ can not be well defined? Or I can't use the notation $f_X*f_Y$?

Comment: I was wrong. You can do this. To evaluate the last integral, you can use the substitution $z = x + y$ so that $dz = dx$, factor the $f_Y$ out of the inner integral and then, since $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are both marginal densities, it all integrates to 1.